# Sharing external hard drive ubuntu 18.04

Tags: samba

I am running Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 on my desktop, and I have 2 external drives connected to it with movies and other stuff, that I share so that I can watch them on my tv using an Android minipc, my phone (also Android), and my wife's laptop with windows 7. Never had a problem, just right click on the drive and share it, and could access them right away.

My computer is very old, with an Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz procesor and 7 Gib of RAM.

Last week I bought an SSD drive and I re-installed the system using it with 2 partitions: boot and /, and left the mechanical hhd for swap, /var, /usr and /home.

I have a second drive in the computer just for data and stuff I want to have handy.

All this time I used to share this second drive, plus another 2, that I connect when I need them, and never had a problem, as I said before. But now after sharing them, I can only see the drives, but if I try to open them, I cannot see the content, my phone says:

> Authentication Fails
>
> The account has no permission

(sorry my phone is in Spanish)

This happens with two of the drives, while with the third one samba doesn't allow me to share giving me error 255.

My goal is to be able to share them as before without having to put any password, that is, that anyone connected to my network is able to access to the drives.

I have tried a bunch of things with no success whatsoever.

If any of you have a way to solve this, I would really appreciate it.
Thank you in advance